# Grabbing the name from data sent through post

Tags: php

When I send over post data I do a print_r($_POST); and I get something like this...

Array ( [gp1] => 9 )

Is there a way to get the "gp1", the name sent over as a value? I tried doing.

```
echo key($_POST["gp1"]);
```

But no luck there, I figured it would echo gp1. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need

```
print_r(array_keys($_POST));
```

check this for more details http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: Looks like all I needed was the built in array_keys() function thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can write `$_POST["gp1"]` you already have the key anyway ;)

[`key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) works differently, it takes an array as argument:

> The `key()` function simply returns the key of the array element that's currently being pointed to by the internal pointer. It does not move the pointer in any way. If the internal pointer points beyond the end of the elements list or the array is empty, `key()` returns NULL.

So if you have not done anything with the array (no traversing), `key($_POST)` would give you the key of the first element of the array.

Maybe you want a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop?

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

}
```

There are other methods to retrieve keys as to well. It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: What I need to do is push the key into a variable as well.

Comment: @Guyver: So? You can assign `$key` to any variable you want to.

Comment: Got what I needed this way...   $test = array_keys($_POST);
echo $test[0];

Comment: @Guyver: Good. As I said it depends on what you want to do actually (but `key($_POST)` should work to then). You can also try `reset($_POST); echo key($_POST));`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `foreach` to see each key-value pair, or use `array_keys` to get a list of all keys.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // Do whatever
}
```